# Will audio render in sync, like when previewing in textured or solid mode?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, audio

I am trying to lip sync a character, which requires timing. In the cycles render engine in textured mode, things are slower but I animated the character that way, so my sound is in sync. But if I go to non texture mode and everything is gray, it's all faster and the sound is out of sync. When I render a movie file will it be at the slower speed and be in sync, or the faster speed like in solid shading. Here is just a little image of the scene if it helps.[image]

Comment: Most likely things are not in sync. During playback you can check the framerate at which the scene is playing. If the numbers are red, it means that is not playing in realtime. Moreover, you are using the "No Sync" option on the timeline (render all frames), try using AV-sync to sync to audio playback dropping frames. The best way to find out if you have errors is rendering a test animation in low res.

Answer (score 1):

It will **not** render it at the slower speed. However, there is a way you could be able to get around this.

- Just look in the upper left corner of the 3D view while the animation is playing, and get its approximate frame rate. (average the values it changes to). [this number is the framerate the animation is playing at due to lag]

[image]

- Now choose a "custom" as the framerate and set the FPS to that average.

[image]

- Alternatively you can use time remapping to adjust the "speed" while still sticking to the target framerate.

This is not the optimal way to do things, and it will not work perfectly, but it is the only way (that I know of) to do what you are asking. Also note that to render it how it looks in the viewport (but at the proper frame rate) use open GL render.

[image]

Unfortunately, this framerate lag is natural, and there isn't much of a way to fix it. If your computer is not fast enough and can not handle processing the info for each frame that fast, it will have to slow down. Here is a picture of my quadcore's (8 thread) workload while running a 1,000,000 particle simulation. The FPS lagged down to 7.

[image]

The arrow is where I stopped the simulation before starting it again. The only way to fix this is to simplify your scene to make it run faster, or use compensations that will help speed things up, like viewing in solid view-port mode. If you move objects that are not necessary while animating to other layers, and have those layers hidden, this will also help. You can also simply hide objects.

**There is a good way to avoid this in the future though!**

Us the A/V sync feature (audio/video sync)

- In the timline, open the "sync" menu.
- Change it to "AV Sync"

[image]

Comment: But why when I have the frame rate at 24 frames per second, does it sometimes say 11 Frames Per Second? And also, since up above your answer, cegaton said its not in real time if it's red, then how do I get it not red and to real time. The reason I ask this is because mine is always red.

Comment: It will automatically play in real time if your computer is fast enough. Unfortunately, if your computer is not fast enough and can not handle processing the info for each frame that fast, it will have to slow down. I will update my answer showing this.

Comment: If you check AV/sync in *Timeline > Playback*, blender will try to keep the playback in time with any sound playing in the VSE (even if it cannot display all the frames quickly enough, in which case it'll skip some instead of falling behind)

Comment: @UncleSnail instead of changing the framerate you can do Time Remapping. That way you can render at the target framerate and make the animation go faster or slower...

Comment: That's a good idea. I'll try to add that when I get around to it. :)

Comment: @cegaton If I render using open Gl render in the solid viewport, should this sync things and make the textures appear, or will there be no texture if i open gl render from solid shading?

Comment: I would not worry about the texture at all. Make sure you can playback at the target framerate, otherwise your work will be wasted or will turn into a nightmare. When you do the final render you'll get your textures and everything will be beautiful and in sync. In the meantime focus on getting the movement for you animation to be correct.

Comment: @Nolan yes, as Cegaton said, regardless of whether you are viewing in textured or solid mode in the viewport, the final render will still look the same, using your Cycles shaders (like it does in "rendered" viewport). Unless you want it to render as it looks in textured viewport, which is what OpenGL render is for. In that case, switch to textured shading before clicking OpenGL render.